# How to add attributes with custom videojs Button

Tags: video.js

I am struggling adding data-attributes to a custom button I have created for an audio js player. It will be a bootstrap collapsible trigger to text files. I think I must use the createEl() function however I can not get it to work with my implementation.

I am trying to add attributes for:

```
'data-toggle': 'collapse',
'data-target': '#' + audioID,
'aria-expanded': 'false'**strong text**
```

thanks for any help you have.

```
let audioBtnComponent = videojs.getComponent('Button')

let audioTextBtn = videojs.extend(audioBtnComponent, {
    constructor: function () {
        audioBtnComponent.apply(this, arguments)
        this.controlText('Toggle text for audio player')
        // this.createEl({}, {}, { 'class': 'Fudge' })
   },
   handleClick: function () {
    accordionElem[i].classList.toggle('audio-text-open')
    audioList[i].closest('.video-js').classList.toggle('audio-text-open')
   },
   buildCSSClass: function () {
       return 'accordion-trigger audio-text-accordion-trigger collapsed'
   },
   //createEl: function (type, properties, attributes) {
     //  return('button', {}, {'data-toggle': 'collapes'})
    //}
})

videojs.registerComponent('audioTextBtn', audioTextBtn)

let audioPlayer = videojs(audioList[i])
audioPlayer.getChild('controlBar').addChild('audioTextBtn', {})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createEl()` should return an element

```
createEl: function () {
  return audioBtnComponent.prototype.createEl.call(this, 'button', {}, {'data-toggle': 'collapes'});
}
```